# Why does getting data from app bundle in for loop causes stackoverflow error

Tags: android, stack-overflow

For the sake of simplicity I will summarize my problem as follows:

A bundle is sent from splash activity to main activity, then it will be sent from main activity to a fragment. In fragment, `this.getArguments()` works perfectly well and it gives the bundle with whatever information we need. Now when I use

```
for(int i=1; i<=bundleSize; i++){
   byte[]  bytes = bundle.getByteArray("byteArray" + i);
//convert bytes to bitmap, etc.
}
```

It causes stackoverflow error. (unable to use method android.os.bundle to string). In fact, it doesn't even go into loop! It just jump from it (unless bundleSize become 1, in that case no error will be thrown). Note that there is no problem with

```
byte[]  bytes = bundle.getByteArray("byteArray" + 1); //or an arbitrary integer
```

And more interestingly enough this one works with no problem as well (I am using it now):

```
while (i++<=bundleSize) {
    byte[]  bytes = bundle.getByteArray("byteArray" + i);
    //convert bytes to bitmap, etc.
}
```

For more information, for (or while) is written in `onCreateView()` and so UI of fragment depends on it. As far as I know, stackoverflow is caused by stacking too much information (Which is not the case here) or infinite loops (again bundleSize is 200 so I think it should not be case as well). I am wondering what's the problem here. Also bundle has String Arrays as well.

Comment: There has got to be a better way to do what you are trying to accomplish anyways. Why not just get the single byte array that you have in your args and then you can build whatever you are building... Doing this on the main thread in on create is not going to end well.

Comment: @Surianto "i" is a local variable which goes from 1 to bundlesize. My keys in bundle is like "byteArray1", "byteArray2", "byteArray3", ... etc

Comment: @RichardDapice There are more than 100 byteArrays in bundle. Each of them corresponds to an image. Well, technically speaking instead of decrypting images and saving them on local disk, I use byteArrays which are inaccessible to user.

Comment: @Surianto Well, java can convert integer to string automatically. For example if you write ""+i it will become "i". Like you know? ""+1="1". In other languages though most of the time you need to convert integer to string first. Also note that in for loop, my thread doesn't even reach to that statement!

Comment: Yeah, at that point I would recommend doing something different with your data than passing it as a bundle.